# How to check JSON request body for REST Api, for object attributes and structure?

Tags: json, node.js, api, rest, express

I am writing my first api (express/node) and one of the endpoints receives json data in the body like:

```
{
    "text": "some comment here...",
    "tags": [ 
        {"id": 0, "tag": "some tag 1"}, 
        {"id": 123, "tag": "some tag 2"}
    ],
    "date": "1452305028289",
}
```

Is there some way you can check that all the properties exist on the object and that they have values? Or do you have to write a custom function checking for each required property and values?

Comment: to check th existance of the 'text' property of your object, try this: `yourObject.hasOwnProperty("text")`, do the same for other properties

Comment: Yeah I figured that was what I had to do, was just wondering if there was some way of comparing one object to another to see if the structure matched, ie properties and nested properties. If the request body has over 15 properties it could get messy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of these packages for validating data with NodeJS:

- https://github.com/hapijs/joi
- https://github.com/mafintosh/is-my-json-valid
- https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be this function that takes an object and a list of strings as the properties of that object:

```
var checkProperties = function (obj, props) {
return props
        .map(function(prop) { return obj.hasOwnProperty(prop); })
        .reduce(function (p, q) { return p && q; });
}
```

use like this

```
checkProperties({ prop1: someValue, prop2: someOtherValue }, ["prop1", "prop2"]); // true
```

Comment: While your solution answers what I asked, the answer by @Alexander Ivantsov gives me more power to validating the JSON that comes in, thank you for your time.

Comment: @CaptRisky No problem